# Paginating foreign key relations

Tags: django-rest-framework

```
class Foo(models.Model):
    pass

class Bar(models.Model):
    foo = models.ForeignKey(Foo, related_name="bars")
```

If a Foo has thousands of Bars, a generic HyperlinkedModelSerializer will render them all. I'm trying to achieve something like `/foos/123/` (shows no Bars) and `/foos/123/bars?limit=x&offset=y` (shows Foo 123's Bars, but paginated).

As far as I can see in DRF's documentation and github issues, LimitOffsetPagination is limited to paginating model instances, not foreignkey relationships. Googling "django rest framework paginate foreignkey" leads nowhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems as though https://github.com/alanjds/drf-nested-routers was built for this very purpose.